# Routing user to another rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, rails-engines, modular

Creating a practice modular application where basically all the functions of the app are contained in engines.

I had a question when it comes to adding another engine. 
Is it possible to route a devise logged in user to a root of that feature.

My goal is to root a user with a specific role to this additional engines root from when a user is logged in. (devise user was generated and configured within the core engine. 2 engines sit within a blank parent application.)

I also have a passthrough controller that routes a user to a specific path. I would like to if possible know how define a path to another engines root within a controller. how would I represent the routing to a specific view within a navigation bar in another engine to a view in another engine.

Also using CanCan is it easy to enable a user to use this engines feature and another user not to. The users will also have different navigation accessibility which will be handled in the cores application layout. will there be problem with rooting a user to that rails engine will it have the same application layout specified in the core engine.

This may seem confusing but any help would be amazing .

Comment: Is your engine namespaced?

Comment: yes it's name spaced along with the Core engine @ValAsensio

Answer (score 1):

An approach that I can think about is through **routes constraints**, so basically you will test if the `current_user` which you can get it from the `request` object have the right permissions

```
## verify if the user/admin is connected
return false unless request.cookie_jar[:auth_token]
Admin.find_by_auth_token(request.cookie_jar.signed[:auth_token])
```

**Rails** engines are mini standalone applications, one way you can get them communicate is via a shared **database**. So you can have the user object for the **main app** and the mounted **engine** that you can perform authorizations/permissions test on it.

Comment: Awesome answer thank you, I think the engine having the shared database might be a little better right ?